# How to Get Line Number of Error in JSfiddle

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsfiddle

Using the below JavaScript, I was able to log the error of the line number in Safari using the JSfiddle editor, but not with Chrome or Firefox. I realize I can get the error of the line number with Firefox using the Firebug plug-in, but **I would like to do the same in Chrome using JSfiddle with Firebug Lite as an external resource**.

```
//I pasted all of this into the JAVASCRIPT portion of jsfiddle editor
//I then pasted the FireBug Lite URL in the External Resources (left menu in jsfiddle) :
//https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js
//then hit enter
try {
  console.log('hello world');
  //console.log(x); //x was never defined
  console.log(x); //x was never defined
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
    //is there a way to include line 8 with the RererenceError?
  //I tried Safari and get this output: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: x {line=55, ...}
  var errorLineNumber = Number(error.line) - 48;
  console.log('Line number of the error is: ' + errorLineNumber) //works in safari to log: Line number of the error is: 8
//In Chrome and Firefox, it logs: Line number of the error is: NaN
} //then clicked Run in JSfiddle
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you using the normal chrome dev tools? I'm pretty sure they are way better than Firebug Lite.

Answer (score 1):

The line number is returned. You need to expand the `…` at

```
ReferenceError: x is not defined(…)
```

After removing comments

```
try {
  console.log("hello world");
  console.log(x); //x was never defined
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

the error would be at line 3. Expanding the `…` reveals

```
at <anonymous>:3:15
```

at chrome, chromium at `console`

Comment: @Mark1010 You could also substitute `console.dir(error)` for `console.log(error)` , which should print `ReferenceError: x is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:15` along with full `ReferenceError` object at `console`

Comment: I was referring to the firebug lite as an external resource in JS fiddle. I tried running your code in JS fiddle and the output, said line 49, not 3: (index):46 hello world
(index):49 ReferenceError: x is not defined
    at window.onload (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:47:15)

Comment: The linked jsfiddle returns `404` error. _"I tried running your code in JS fiddle and the output, said line 49, not 3:"_ Did you remove all of the comments?

Comment: Yes, here is the jsfiddle I just tried: https://jsfiddle.net/vju5bt1r/1/

Comment: @Mark1010 Apparently `firebug-lite-debug`  does not log line number of error

Comment: @Mark1010 See also [Taking Chrome DevTools outside of the browser.](https://kenneth.io/blog/2014/12/28/taking-chrome-devtools-outside-the-browser/)

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there is a way to obtain it from the error object in firebug lite; I was able to in Safari by logging the error line and then subtracting (see original code posted). The console.dir(error) will be helpful in the future.